# Array of pointers - memory allocation

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc

I'm new into array of pointers (putting functions into array) and allocating memory for it using malloc. Can you help me with this piece of code? Have functions: `int comp_int(int a, int b); int comp_int_abs(int a, int b); int comp_int_length(int a, int b); int comp_int_digits_sum(int a, int b);`
and would like to put pointers to these functions in array of pointers. Firstly would like to dynamically allocate memory for the array and put functions' pointers into it. Stuck in this place, what am I doing wrong?

```
int (**funcs)(int, int) = malloc(4*sizeof(int));

if(!*funcs)
{
    printf("Failed to allocate memory");
    return 8;
}

*funcs={add_int, sub_int, div_int, mul_int};
```

Comment: Regarding the `malloc` calculation, you should almost always use the form `something = malloc(NumberOfThings * sizeof *something)`. That way, whether something is a pointer to a function or a pointer to a structure or whatever, `sizeof *something` is always the size of whatever `something` points to. So it is always the right size. So `int (**funcs)(int, int) = malloc(4 * sizeof *funcs);` would be right.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks, didn't know ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, why allocate dynamic memory?

If you use a normal array, things get a bit simpler:

```
int (*funcs[])(int, int) = {
    comp_int,
    comp_int_abs,
    comp_int_length,
    comp_int_digits_sum,
};
```

If you want to use dynamic allocation, there are a few things to look out for.

```
int (**funcs)(int, int) = malloc(4 * sizeof *funcs);
```

First we need to allocate the right amount of memory. By multiplying with the size of the dereferenced pointer, we don't have to worry about the element type of the dynamic array. (But if we wanted to write the type manually, it would be `sizeof (int (*)(int, int))`, not `sizeof (int)` as in your code; the elements of our array are pointers to functions, not integers.)

Then we check for allocation failure:

```
if (!funcs) {
```

Note: We check the pointer itself (`funcs`), not the first element of the dynamic array (which may not exist!) as in your code (`*funcs`). If `malloc` fails and returns `NULL`, then `!*funcs` will try to dereference a null pointer, which will most likely crash your program.

```
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate memory\n");
```

Error messages go to `stderr`, not `stdout`. Lines are terminated by `'\n'`.

```
    return 8;
}
```

Since we don't have a real array here, we can't use initialization syntax. In particular, `= {` is not valid in assignment expressions.

The most straightforward solution is to assign the elements manually:

```
funcs[0] = comp_int;
funcs[1] = comp_int_abs;
funcs[2] = comp_int_length;
funcs[3] = comp_int_digits_sum;
```

It's a bit error prone because we have to specify every index manually. However, we can combine this with the "normal array" code from above:

```
int (*const funcs_init[])(int, int) = {
    comp_int,
    comp_int_abs,
    comp_int_length,
    comp_int_digits_sum,
};

int (**funcs)(int, int) = malloc(sizeof funcs_init);
if (!funcs) { ... }

memcpy(funcs, funcs_init, sizeof funcs_init);
```

We just initialize our array as usual (here called `funcs_init`), then copy the contents into our dynamically allocated memory using `memcpy`.

Comment: Thanks you for the complex explanation! This is for studying purposes and the task I have to do is to dynamically allocate the memory. I know, thing would be simpler without that way.

Answer (score 1):

First, change the allocation from:

```
int (**funcs)(int, int)=malloc(4*sizeof(int));
```

to

```
int (**funcs)(int, int)=malloc(4*sizeof(*funcs));
```

Change

```
*funcs={add_int, sub_int, div_int, mul_int};
```

to

```
funcs[0]=add_int;
funcs[1]=sub_int;
funcs[2]=div_int;
funcs[3]=mul_int;
```

The notation with braces, {} can only be used upon initializations and not assignments. If you use an array instead of a pointer, you can do this:

```
int (*funcs[4])(int, int)={add_int, sub_int, div_int, mul_int};
```